# How do I add a soundcloud follow button to my website without authentication?

Tags: soundcloud

On my band website, I'd like for visitors to be able to follow us on soundcloud with one click (assuming they are already signed in to soundcloud). Is this possible?

There is a Soundcloud API for this, I think:

```
/users/{id}/followings/{id}
```

But this requires authentication, which is more clicks than ideal.

Facebook provides a solution for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button/

Is there something analogous for Soundcloud?

Comment: I'm imagining not, because the authentication is a protection layer to prevent the end-user from being "duped" into clicking the "Follow" button without knowing it via tricks like CSS or Javascript.

Comment: That makes sense. On the other hand, other platforms like facebook, twitter, and youtube allow for this, which is why I was hoping soundcloud might do the same.

Comment: It's really up to the discretion of the developers of the API. I'd suggest making a hook after a successful follow that enables a free download for the user. It's a popular way to gain legitimate followers.

Comment: That would be cool. Do you know of any examples? I actually built [something similar for twitter and facebook](http://lowcountrykingdom.com/share). But they make this much smoother than what appears to be exposed by soundcloud. For example, I can give the user a dialog, via a twitter Web Intent, that allows them to compose a tweet about us, and then call back to my own javascript to serve up the download. Facebook provides a similar interface for a share dialog. All of this without authorizing my app. Understood that this is up to soundcloud -- I'm just adding my 2c that this would be useful.